# Что означает приставка Foo?

Tags: php, классы

Я часто встречаю данную приставку когда наследуют от предопределенного класс например как mysqli, другой класс что наследует этот класс называют Foo_mysqli.
Вот хочу разобраться, что оно означает от кого слова идет сокращение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Это слова-заменители, которые применяются в технических текстах для обозначения чего-либо, что может стоять на их месте, метапеременные часто используются в программировании.

- http://habrahabr.ru/post/112210/
- http://alfuken.tumblr.com/post/870015866/foo-bar-and-friends
- [Metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable)
- [Метапеременные](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метапеременные)

А пошло это от армейского сокращения `FUBAR`, что означает `"F..ked Up Beyond All Recognition"`

Answer (score 1):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo